# create Table for sale 2015 and2016

Tags: sql

i have the Sale Table at the bottom:

Now i want to create a Table to compare the sale figure from the date this year to the same date last year. the result which i would like to have is:

```
Saledate2016        salevolume2016       saledate2015       salevolume2015 

2016.01.01          10                   2015.01.01         10    
2016.02.01          20                   2015.02.01         20    
2016.03.01          20                   2015.03.01         10    
2016.04.01          60                   2016.04.01         50    
2016.05.01          10                   2016.05.01         10
```

Can you please help me how to do it?

Thanks

```
CREATE TABLE
Saletotal (Saledate date, Salevolume int)
INSERT INTO Saletotal (Saledate, Salevolume)
VALUES
('2016.01.01', 10),
('2016.02.01', 20),
('2016.03.01', 20),
('2016.04.01', 60),
('2016.05.01', 10),
('2015.01.01', 10),
('2015.02.01', 20),
('2015.03.01', 10),
('2015.04.01', 50),
('2015.05.01', 10)
```

Comment: Self join, perhaps outer needed.

Comment: I think that's not a good table design

Comment: i used it to create diagram on SSRS

Comment: Nothing wrong with that table...

Comment: Tag the dbms you're using. (When it comes to date/time many products are far from ANSI SQL compliant.)

Comment: If your rdbms is Oracle, or Sql server, you can use the lead function (very useful). using this,  you dont need self join.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a solution that works in SQL Server:

```
select s2016.Saledate Saledate2016, 
s2016.Salevolume SaleVolume2016, 
s2015.Saledate SaleDate2015, 
s2015.Salevolume SaleVolume2015
from Saletotal s2016
join Saletotal s2015 on s2015.Saledate = dateadd(year, -1, s2016.SaleDate)
```